# How to use 3 conditions in SQL properly which is SUBSTRING, IF ELSE, EXISTS on making a data unique?

Tags: php, mysql

So I haven't figured out my problem when it comes to my query, I want to get the first 3 strings of my data and make it unique for example I inputted GTX-2070 if I input another first 3 strings that is GTX-3070 it should not be accepted because the first 3 initial is already used. I tried to do this first in mysQL query.

Here is my code in mySQL

```sql
SELECT (CASE WHEN (IF EXISTS(SELECT SUBSTRING(control_no, 1, 3) FROM tools_masterlist BEGIN INSERT IGNORE INTO tools_masterlist (tools_id, tools_name, control_no)
VALUES ('value a', 'value b', 'value c') END) THEN 'Error input' ELSE = 'Okay' END)) FROM tools_masterlist WHERE control_no = 'GTX-2070'
```

I am still figuring it out because I got errors in mySQL query and can't find the solution. Thank you for the help

Comment: Code in a screen shot is hard to read, if you can, post it in your post as text.  And if you need it to be unique, why not make it a constraint on the table definition?  `column_name data_type UNIQUE` for that particular column.  That should raise an error if a non-unique item is inserted.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements with placeholder values** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](https://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One sensisble option here would be to add a `prefix` column and make it unique:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tools_masterlist ADD prefix VARCHAR(3);
ALTER TABLE tools_masterlist ADD CONSTRAINT cnstr_prefix UNIQUE (prefix);
```

When you insert, now also specify the prefix.  Attempting to insert a `control_no` whose prefix already exists in the table will fail with an error.

Comment: Additional column is excess. `ALTER TABLE tools_masterlist ADD UNIQUE unique_idx (control_no(3));` is enough. PS. You forget to specify the expression for generated column.

Comment: @Akina Well I was wondering whether or not this three letter prefix might deserve having its own column.  Your suggestion should also work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It did work well, however I have a question @Akina is unique_idx the name of the index?

Comment: @keitha-zA-Z0-9 *is unique_idx the name of the index?* True. You may replace it with any other name easily and even skip at all (it will be autogenerated).